# Sed to add new line while replacing comma

Tags: bash, sed

I have a list like below :
release=abc,xyz,pqr,bnm
and as output I need

```
abc
xyz
pqr
bnm
```

I have tried below using sed , it successfully removes , but not able to insert new line after comma , if can help pls

```
release=abc,xyz,pqr,bnm
for i in $release;do
    b=`echo $i| sed 's/,/\\n/g'`
    echo $b
done
```

output: abc xyz pqr bnm which is not expected here as need new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a loop, as the `i` in the loop is `abc,xyz,pqr,bnm`

You could also just translate the newlines to commas:

```
release=abc,xyz,pqr,bnm
tr , '\n' <<< $release
```

Output

```
abc
xyz
pqr
bnm
```

If there should be a non whitespace char other than a comma before actually match the comma, you can use `sed` with a capture group:

```
release=abc,xyz,pqr,bnm
sed 's/\([^[:space:],]\),/\1\n/g' <<< $release
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
release=abc,xyz,pqr,bnm

echo "${release//,/$'\n'}"
```

Output

```
abc
xyz
pqr
bnm
```

---

With your approach using `sed`

```
release=abc,xyz,pqr,bnm

echo "$release" | sed 's/,/\n/g'
```

Comment: thank you , but whenever I pass this in variable it again changes so ```release=abc,xyz,pqr,bnm
for i in $release;do
    echo "$i"|sed 's/,/\n/g'
done```   is okay but ``` release=abc,xyz,pqr,bnm
for i in $release;do
    name=`echo "$i"|sed 's/,/\n/g'`
    echo $name
done``` is giving wrong , if can suggest

Comment: You don't need the loop, just the code above.

Comment: thanks that works okay .. but again my requirement was to have this in for loop to run based upon  release=abc,xyz,pqr,bnm values and so was looking

Comment: Can you please edit your question, also what about a while loop? Is it accepted? or just a for loop?